# activity for in-app billing errors that google play displays in notification area

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have android application that uses in-app purchases.

When I **try to purchase** item and **don't have enough money** on card, **Google Play places notification in notification area** (purchase failed), and click on that notification opens my application with initial activity.

**Can I**:
0) make google play don't add this notification to notification area?
1) set intent for activity to be launched on this notification click?